# Meteor simple-schema: how to get the value of another field that isn't set

Tags: meteor

I'd like to know the value of another field even when that field hasn't been set in this update, but is part of the document and was set in the past. Is this possible using aldeed:simple-schema?

Comment: Would you please post a code sample to better describe your needs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Unless the other field is included in the *modifier* you have to lookup the document using *Collection.findOne* and get the field value from that.

Answer (score -1):

Simple you can use for instance:

```
AutoForm.getFieldValue('profileInformation.dateOfBirth');

age: {
    type: String,
    optional: true,
    defaultValue : function(){
        return AutoForm.getFieldValue('profileInformation.dateOfBirth');
    }
}
```